# get all CheckBoxes spread over several views in Android

Tags: java, android, layout, android-edittext, android-checkbox

My activity contains several `EditText`s and `CheckBox`es. Some of them are dynamically added by the user. I want to have an Array of all `EditText`- and `CheckBox`-objects.
I use LinearLayout, RelativeLayout and TableLayout in my XML.
I tried this:

```
public void getAllEditTextsAndCheckBoxes(View view){

    ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();

    for (int i = 0; i < this.mainScrollView.getFocusables(View.FOCUS_FORWARD).size(); i++) {

       View actualView = mainScrollView.getFocusables(View.FOCUS_FORWARD).get(i);


        if(actualView instanceof EditText) {
            views.add((EditText) actualView);
        }
        if(actualView instanceof CheckBox) {
            views.add((CheckBox) actualView);
        }

    }

}
```

But this gives me only the `EditText`s and not a single `CheckBox`
Here is the structure of my messy xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView>
   <LinearLayout>
      <!-- several LinearLayouts and Buttons-->
      <RelativeLayout>
         <TableLayout>
            <TableRow>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
               <EditText/>
               **<CheckBox/>**
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>
               <EditText/>
               **<CheckBox/>**
            </TableRow>
         </TableLayout>
      </RelativeLayout>
   <!-- some other LinearLayouts and Buttons -->
   </LinearLayout>
```

(I tried to leave out the unimportant information but since I don't know how much you need, I could not make it very short: http://pastebin.com/DnQnxtVJ)

Comment: Can you please share us your xml file having the layout structure as well because Ideally ScrollView can have only one child. So inside ScrollView you to first define a container and need to add everything inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested your module with the given layout and it's returning the result as expected. I've created a Fragment and passed the xml as a layout for it. Once the fragment gets added to the activity. I am able to extract all checkboxes and EditText views. Checked through the added logs.

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        getAllEditTextsAndCheckBoxes(view);

    }

    public void getAllEditTextsAndCheckBoxes(View view){

        ArrayList<View> returnViews = new ArrayList<View>();

        ArrayList<View> focusableViews = view.getFocusables(View.FOCUS_FORWARD);

        for (int i = 0; i < focusableViews.size(); i++) {

            View actualView = focusableViews.get(i);

            if(actualView instanceof EditText) {
                returnViews.add((EditText) actualView);
            }
            if(actualView instanceof CheckBox) {
                returnViews.add((CheckBox) actualView);
            }

        }

        for(View mView: returnViews){
            if (mView instanceof  EditText){
                Log.d("ash_sow", "EditText Found!!");
            }
            else if(mView instanceof CheckBox){
                Log.d("ash_sow", "CheckBox Found!!");
            }
        }

    }
```

So I think It might be happening when you trying to add the component at runtime or it could be some other issue. So just try again and have a closer look at the probable suspects.

Comment: Ok so I use an Activity and called `getAllEditTextsAndCheckBoxes(View view)` at the end of my `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and it worked.
But it does not work, when `getAllEditTextsAndCheckBoxes(View view)` is called by pressing a button with `android:onClick="getAllEditTextsAndCheckBoxes"`. Any ideas why?

Comment: It's not gonna work that way because if you define the onClick event on your xml then the method will take button view as a reference argument in your getAllEditTextsAndCheckBoxes method. What you should do is define a click listener for this button on your Activity class and on it's onClick(View view) method call getAllEditTextsAndCheckBoxes(<reference of your scroll view>)

Comment: Ah ok I think I understand. Do I have to do the same, if I want to call the getAllEditTextsAndCheckBoxes method whenever an EditText or a CheckBox is edited? And do you want to add that information to your answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: If you need to call getAllEditTextsAndCheckBoxes on EditText or Checkbox then you have to add the relevant listeners for them like for EditText you can add TextWatcher & for CheckBox you can use CheckedChangeListener. I think if you have got the solution of your problem then you can accept it because there is not much in the proposed solution it's just for making things clear to you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried getting all the children of the relevant views and iterating through them? I have never used `getFocusables()` myself. Maybe checkboxes aren't focusable and only clickable hence them not appearing? If so, you can perhaps try adding `.setFocusable(true)` when you create the objects.

Otherwise, I would do it like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<((ViewGroup)ViewGroupToIterate).getChildCount(); i++) {
    View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)ViewGroupToIterate).getChildAt(i);
    if(nextChild instanceof EditText) {
        views.add((EditText) actualView);
    }
    if(nextChild instanceof CheckBox) {
        views.add((CheckBox) actualView);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. `android:focusable="true"` looked promising but it did not work :(
The problem with iterating through the children is that I have nested views. getChild only gets the direct children and not the grand children right?
So I would have some nasty nested loops. I would like to avoid that :)